# data.table left join with condition

Tags: r, conditional-statements, data.table, left-join

I would like to left join Y to X using id as joining variable and a condition. All rows of X should be kept. Here is a minimal example:

```
X <- data.table( 
    id = 1:5
  , start = 1:5
  , end   = 5:9
  , x = LETTERS[1:5]
)

Y <- data.table(
    id = 3:5
  , date = c(1,5,7)
  , y = letters[3:5]
)

X
   id start end x
1:  1     1   5 A
2:  2     2   6 B
3:  3     3   7 C
4:  4     4   8 D
5:  5     5   9 E
                
Y
   id date y
1:  3    1 c
2:  4    5 d
3:  5    7 e
```

I used this to join:

```
Y[X,on=.(id=id, between(date,start, end))]
```

and expected this:

```
    id date x start end y
1:  1    NA NA    1   5 A
2:  2    NA NA    2   6 B
3:  3    NA NA    3   7 C
4:  4    5  d     4   8 D
5:  5    7  e     5   9 E
```

but got the following error:

```
Error in colnamesInt(x, names(on), check_dups = FALSE) : 
  argument specifying columns specify non existing column(s): cols[2]='between(date, start, end)'
```

Any idea how to cope with a left join and conditions?

UPDATE 1:
In real data happens that due to between condition there can be multiple links from X to Y. If I change X and Y to:

```
X <- data.table( 
    id = c(1:5,5)
  , start = c(1:5,10)
  , end   = c(5:9,14)
  , x = LETTERS[1:5]
)

Y <- data.table(
    id = 3:5
  , date = c(1,5,7)
  , y = letters[3:5]
)

Y <- rbind(Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y)
```

I get this message:

```
 Y[with(X[match(Y$id, id)], between(Y$date, start, end))][X, on=.(id)]

Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
 Join results in 39 rows; more than 30 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for 
 duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in 
 x over and over again. If that`s ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for 
 each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish 
 to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please 
 search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and 
 data.table issue tracker for advice.
```

If I set

```
Y[with(X[match(Y$id, id)], between(Y$date, start, end))
         ][X, on=.(id),allow.cartesian=TRUE]
```

this gives a cartesian product by `id` what I don't want.

The correct result without error/warnings delivers this sql:

```
sqldf("SELECT X.*, Y.date, Y.y
       FROM X
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Y ON X.id = Y.id 
            AND Y.date BETWEEN X.start AND X.end
       ")
```

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because *start* and *end* don't exist in *Y*.

Alternatively `replace` the values after the join since you want to keep all rows anyways.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

merge(X, Y, "id", all=T) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(date, y), ~ replace(.x, !between(date, start, end), NA)))
   id start end x date    y
1:  1     1   5 A   NA <NA>
2:  2     2   6 B   NA <NA>
3:  3     3   7 C   NA <NA>
4:  4     4   8 D    5    d
5:  5     5   9 E    7    e
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subset `Y` using `between` on `match`ing columns, then join with `X`.

```
> Y[with(X[match(Y$id, id)], between(Y$date, start, end))][X, on=.(id)]
   id date    y start end x
1:  1   NA <NA>     1   5 A
2:  2   NA <NA>     2   6 B
3:  3   NA <NA>     3   7 C
4:  4    5    d     4   8 D
5:  5    7    e     5   9 E
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I have to admit that it is quite a workaround. For small tables I will use the more readible sql version `sqldf("SELECT X.*, Y.date, Y.y FROM X LEFT OUTER JOIN Y ON X.id = Y.id AND Y.date BETWEEN X.start AND X.end")` but for large tables I will use your solution.

Comment: When I apply this to my real data I got this error message: `Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  :  Join results in 346 rows; more than 155 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker for advice.`
See update 1.